# customizing componnet in joomla

Tags: joomla

i have created a component using this http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/index.php component creator how can i add a simple registration form in that and also make its backend looks like the other component

Comment: that is a great tool to generate skeleton for the component. but you need to program it to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Use tools like that builder just to start. One you have the annoying stuff out of the way like file structure of a component, its relatively simple. Joomla Doc shows many examples of how to do this [http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Development)

Answer (score 1):

The name of that utility is a little misleading since it only creates the structure of a component. If you want to add functionality to the structure created you will need to actually put in the code that does what ever you need it to do. Think of this as the foundation and framework of a house. You actually have to put the walls up and furnish it.

It would probably be helpful to understand the files that have been created for you so you know what needs to be added. I would recommend learning how to build a component from scratch first. Joomla has pretty good documentation on that here - http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

Comment: That is right, Joomla 101. This can be helpful http://docs.joomla.org/Developers, will help to see the big picture.

Answer (score 1):

i have develop the Lots of component from this site http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/index.php . 
1) First Create the components and give the name and crrate the require field fo the registration from .and save the components then after the download this components.

2) Install the components in your joomla site.

3)  Go to the Fornt-end view components folder. and  create a form in the default.php page and  save and update operation query is written in the model   .

Your Registration page is ready.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components) is the best I have come across so far. It will hopefully guide you to understand the MVC structure that the component generating site delivers to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually the developer of the [Component Creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/index.php) you have used. It only creates the MVC files and structures needed to quickly create a component. You still need quite good PHP skills to develop a fully working component.

The component creator helps developers with the tedious tasks of building the framework.